# HOW to prevent an ASP.net PageMethod call from blocking other javascript function calls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous, pagemethods

The JavaScript function below runs every 15 seconds and calls an ASP.Net Page-method. It takes about 4 - 8 seconds to complete.

I also have another JavaScript function on the same page that runs every 2 seconds, but gets periodically blocked by the previous method that takes longer to complete.

```
function get_case_list_data(count, max_id) {
   PageMethods.GetCaseList(count, max_id, uid, is_agent, got_case_list_data, OnFailure);
}
```

Please how can we prevent an ASP.Net Page-method call from blocking other JavaScript function execution on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the browser debug tools and inspect the auto-generated code used in PageMethods.GetCaseList then just mimic the call with an async ajax call instead of a blocking one.

The PageMethods wrapper is just for convenience but that code is normally pretty ugly.  You can always manually call it your self with $.ajax or native XmlHttpRequest.

async = true;

If your making multiple calls, the ASP.NET session may be doing the blocking.   Use alerts or console.log within the javascript methods to determine what is blocking

```
function get_case_list_data(count, max_id) {
   console.log("before call");
   PageMethods.GetCaseList(count, max_id, uid, is_agent, got_case_list_data, OnFailure);
   console.log("after call");
}

function got_case_list_data(){
   console.log("in PageMethod success");
   // -- updated --
   // this could be blocking the call to/from other 2 second timer
   // JS is single thread, so window.timeout and ajax callbacks will
   // wait until the function is exited
   // -- end update--
   console.log("end of PageMethod success");
}
```

-- updated--

setting the asp.net session to readonly removed the exclusive session lock that would synchronize the threads

Comment: so basically the calls are not asynchronous?

Comment: You can test this with an alert before, after the PageMethod call and within the success callback.   Google "aysnc PageMethods" it appears they may be aysnc by default and you'll need make updates to make it syncronouse.   Either way this blog has some good content to get you started.   http://abhijit-j-shetty.blogspot.com/2011/04/aspnet-ajax-calling-pagemethods.html

Comment: Tried $ajax with async = true; same result

Comment: the link you gave is for synchronous calls... I thought that was the problem?

Comment: I had already added the cosole.log and removed all the session usage - no difference

Comment: The blocking may be happing within the "got_case_list_data" callback method and not within the "get_case_list_data".    You can use your browser debugger profiling tools to see where its blocking

Comment: Please I do not follow the previous comment

Comment: added and [updated] section above to explain that the blocking is probably in the callback method and not in the method calling the PageMethod

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115908/discussion-between-charles-okwuagwu-and-steve).